# Deedle normalize frame

Tags: f#, deedle

How to normalize data in deedle frame ?

I've tried this approach but one doesn't work

```
 let iris = Frame.ReadCsv("./iris.csv")
 let keys = iris.ColumnKeys |> Seq.toArray
 let x = iris.Columns.[keys.[0..4]]
 let mu = x |> Stats.mean 
 let std = x |> Stats.stdDev
 //Not working becasue couldnt substract series from frame 
 let norm = (x - mu) / std
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `frame - series` overload expects that you are subtracting the `series` from all columns of the `frame`, i.e. that the row keys of the frame and the row keys of the series align.

For your use case, you need to align the column keys - there is no single operator for this, but you can do it using the `mapRows` function:

```
let x = iris.Columns.[keys.[0..3]]
let mu = x |> Stats.mean 
let std = x |> Stats.stdDev

let norm = 
  x 
  |> Frame.mapRowValues (fun r -> (r.As<float>() - mu) / std)
  |> Frame.ofRows
```

I also changed your `x` to be just from `keys.[0..3]` because otherwise you'd be trying to normalize column of type `string`, which fails.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I've also tried use mapRowValues and that I fail to understand is that `.As` operator needed for this. Docs little bit unclear about this.

Comment: This is because Deedle sadly does not know that the rows are all numeric (which they are actually not, if you do not drop the fourth column) - calling `row.As<float>()` turns a row of type `Series<int, obj>` into `Series<int, float>` which supports the `-` operator.